# SceneKit - SCNText centering incorrectly

Tags: swift, scenekit, scntext

I have tried to make a text string (SCNText) fit inside a box (SCNBox) in the code below. The size of the box looks correct but the text is not in the right center of the box. Any idea or solution? Thanks

```
let geoText = SCNText(string: "Hello", extrusionDepth: 1.0)
geoText.font = UIFont (name: "Arial", size: 8)
geoText.firstMaterial!.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
let textNode = SCNNode(geometry: geoText)

let (minVec, maxVec) = textNode.boundingBox
scnScene.rootNode.addChildNode(textNode)

let w = CGFloat(maxVec.x - minVec.x)
let h = CGFloat(maxVec.y - minVec.y)
let d = CGFloat(maxVec.z - minVec.z)

let geoBox = SCNBox(width: w, height: h, length: d, chamferRadius: 0)
geoBox.firstMaterial!.diffuse.contents = UIColor.green.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
scnScene.rootNode.addChildNode(boxNode)
```

[image: The text is not the center of the box]

**Edited:** I have added a new image of the string only (no SCNBox node) with debugOptions showBoundingBoxes to see its bounding box

[image]

**Solution 1:**

From vdugnist's answer, I create a playground code for anyone who wants to test:

```
import UIKit
import SceneKit
import PlaygroundSupport

var sceneView = SCNView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 600, height: 600))
var scene = SCNScene()
sceneView.scene = scene
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = sceneView

let geoText = SCNText(string: "Hello", extrusionDepth: 1.0)
geoText.font = UIFont (name: "Arial", size: 12)
geoText.firstMaterial!.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
let textNode = SCNNode(geometry: geoText)

let (minVec, maxVec) = textNode.boundingBox
textNode.position = SCNVector3(x: (minVec.x - maxVec.x) / 2, y: minVec.y - maxVec.y, z: 0)
textNode.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation((maxVec.x - minVec.x) / 2, 0, 0)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(textNode)

let w = CGFloat(maxVec.x - minVec.x)
let h = CGFloat(maxVec.y - minVec.y)
let d = CGFloat(maxVec.z - minVec.z)

let geoBox = SCNBox(width: w, height: h, length: d, chamferRadius: 0)
geoBox.firstMaterial!.diffuse.contents =   UIColor.green.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
let boxNode = SCNNode(geometry: geoBox)
boxNode.position = SCNVector3Make((maxVec.x - minVec.x) / 2 + minVec.x, (maxVec.y - minVec.y) / 2 + minVec.y, 0);
textNode.addChildNode(boxNode)
```

[image]

**Solution 2:**

I need to move the text to position zero (0, 0, 0) instead of moving both text and the around box, thus I continue to change the pivot of the text from Solution 1. Now the code is as the following:

```
import UIKit
import SceneKit
import PlaygroundSupport


var sceneView = SCNView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 600, height: 600))
var scene = SCNScene()
sceneView.scene = scene
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = sceneView


let geoText = SCNText(string: "Hello", extrusionDepth: 1.0)
geoText.font = UIFont (name: "Arial", size: 12)
geoText.firstMaterial!.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
let textNode = SCNNode(geometry: geoText)

let (minVec, maxVec) = textNode.boundingBox
textNode.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation((maxVec.x - minVec.x) / 2 + minVec.x, (maxVec.y - minVec.y) / 2 + minVec.y, 0)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(textNode)

let w = CGFloat(maxVec.x - minVec.x)
let h = CGFloat(maxVec.y - minVec.y)
let d = CGFloat(maxVec.z - minVec.z)

let geoBox = SCNBox(width: w, height: h, length: d, chamferRadius: 0)
geoBox.firstMaterial!.diffuse.contents = UIColor.green.withAlphaComponent(0.6)
let boxNode = SCNNode(geometry: geoBox)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(boxNode)
```

Comment: Did Apple stoped SceneKit support ?  At WWDC21 I did not see anything about it so far.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The difference of SCNText from other geometries is that SCNText origin point positioned at bottom left corner. In other geometries, it is a bottom center.

To fix text position in parent node you can set its pivotPoint.x to half of width:

```
SCNVector3 min, max;
[textNode getBoundingBoxMin:&min max:&max];
textNode.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation((max.x - min.x) / 2, 0, 0);
```

To fix subnodes position, you should set their position to half of width plus min:

```
SCNVector3 min, max;
[textNode getBoundingBoxMin:&min max:&max];
subnode.position = SCNVector3Make((max.x - min.x) / 2 + min.x, (max.y - min.y) / 2 + min.y, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks, but look like it is not a solution (I have tried but it is worse - perhaps I don't get all your ideas?). Logically, in my question image, the central point is not in the right position for both axes x and y. Your answer has just tried to fix x only, clearly it is not enough. It is the best if you post a full fix code here.

Comment: Can you try to add box node as a child of text node instead of a root node, using coordinates from my second solution?

The problem that I see in your code is that you're getting boundingBox from textNode, which returned in textNode coordinate system, and using them in rootNode coordinate system.

Comment: This works for me decently I think this is what you want? `textNode.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation((max.x - min.x) / 2 + min.x, (max.y - min.y) / 2 + min.y, 0);`

Answer (score 11):

**Swift:** center text-node in parent-node correctly

```
let (min, max) = textNode.boundingBox

let dx = min.x + 0.5 * (max.x - min.x)
let dy = min.y + 0.5 * (max.y - min.y)
let dz = min.z + 0.5 * (max.z - min.z)
textNode.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(dx, dy, dz)

let textNodeParent = SCNNode()
textNodeParent.addChildNode(textNode)
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the center of the bounding box you need to add (not subtract) the min and max before you divide by 2.

```
textNode.position = SCNVector3(x: (minVec.x + maxVec.x) / 2, y: minVec.y + maxVec.y, z: 0)
```

Comment: Sorry, but it is not the right answer. I take the point(0, 0, 0) as the center, similar to the box, not to move the text far aways as your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be getting bitten by SCNText's unusual treatment of origin. IIRC the Y zero is at the string's baseline, not at the bottom of the descenders.

Turn on `showBoundingBoxes` In the `debugOptions` and see if that helps.

Comment: I have turned on all debug options and checked already. All look good. Thus I have no clue. Perhaps it is an API bug (since the code is so simple and the logic is quite clear)!?

Comment: It's unlikely to be an API bug. But since it isn't working the way you expect, it legitimately could be a documentation bug. Can we see a screenshot with bounding boxes turned on?

Comment: I cannot add the image here (in this comment). Thus I have edited my question to add that image. More info is better anyways